# Impact of Google Chrome blocking Flash at the end of the year

Tags: magento2, magento-1, 3rd-party-library

As some of you may know [Google Chrome will start blocking Flash in December](http://thenextweb.com/dd/2016/08/09/google-chrome-flash/#gref)

I know that the backend uploaded of M1 is using Flash.

What is the impact of no flash for Magento ? What other features are using flash and can't work without it ?

I'd like to get answers for both M1 and M2

Update: according to one of the Magento developer, a 1.x update that drops flash support is coming soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Magento 1.9:

```
$ find -name "*.swf"./js/tiny_mce/plugins/media/moxieplayer.swf
./skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
./skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
./skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
```

So it would be the uploader "only" and some media player currently affected

For Magento 2.1.0:

```
$ find -name "*.swf" 
./lib/web/tiny_mce/plugins/media/moxieplayer.swf
```

Only that player is the remaining Flash file. It is a "Fallback player for AS3" - some video streams I believe.

As long as you don't use such streams in your CMS content, I don't think there will be an impact - and as this is a fallback player, there also is probably a HTML5 player already implemented.